# Mod Security Whitelisting IP's With A Single File Location on Multiple Servers?

Tags: whitelist

Just need pointed in the right direction.

I need to manage whitelisting of IP's on multiple servers for ModSecurity. As whitelists grow, I'd rather have a single .txt file to maintain where each modsec instance checks against it and executes the whitelist. I need to add 100's of IP's now on 30 servers, and I don't see updating that to each one. Hopefully that makes sense.

Currently the below works on each server, but is there a way to put a reference to a file we'll call `/file/location/whitelist.txt` (that I can maintain from one spot) in here instead of all the IP's listed individually on each server?

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx" \
 "id:10001,\
 phase:1,\
 pass,\
 nolog,\
 ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

Comment: I'm thinking there has to be a way to insert a reference to another file location for the @ipmatch to draw from. Hmmm....

Answer (score 0):

How about using a network share to store said file.

Something like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<win_share_user> //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /file/location
```

Then you have a single file located on another server WIN_SHARE_IP, although it doesn't have to be windows.  All 30 machines reference this file.

For security reason the 30 machines should all see this file as read-only.

You can create another user name for yourself on the master server with read-write permissions.